# Change text of button that I clicked on

Tags: reactjs, button, onclick, state

I have a few buttons on my component that are being rendered when I map through an array. There is a button for every item in the array. When I click on a specific button, I want the text for only that button at that specific index to change. Currently, the text for all the buttons is changing. I'm not quite sure how to fix the problem. Here's what I have so far:

```
export default class Profile extends React.Component{
  state = {
    profile: [],
    events: [],
    disabledButton: -1,
    eventifySent: false
  }

  static contextType = UserContext

  componentDidMount() {
    ProfileService.getProfileById(this.props.match.params.id)
      .then(profile => {
        this.setState({ profile: profile})

      const profileId = this.state.profile.user_id

    EventService.getAllEvents()
      .then( event => {
        const profileEvents = event.filter(e => e.event_owner_id === profileId)
        this.setState({ events: profileEvents})
      })
    })  
  }

  handleIntriguedButton = (id, index) => {
    EventifyService.postEventify({
      recipient_id: this.props.match.params.id,
      event: id,
    })
    .then( response => {
        console.log(response)

      this.setState({ 
        disabledButton: index, 
        eventifySent: true
      }) }
    )
  }

  render() {
    const user = this.state.profile
    const events = this.state.events

    console.log(this.state.disabledButton)

    const userEvents = (events.length === 0 ) ? 'I have no events yet' 
    : events.map((event, i) => 
      <div key={event.id} className="event">
        <p>{event.event_name}</p>
        <button type="submit" disabled={this.state.disabledButton === i} onClick={() => this.handleIntriguedButton(event.id, i)}>{!this.state.eventifySent && this.state.disabledButton !== i ? ('Intrigued') : ('Eventify sent!')}</button>
      </div> 
    )
    return (
      <div className="profile">
        <img src={user.profile_picture} alt=''/>
        <p>Bio: {user.me_intro}</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Music: {user.music_like}</li>
          <li>Favorite movie: {user.movie_like}</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Events:</p>
        <div className="profile-events">
          {userEvents}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I thought I was selecting the specific index of that button, but I guess I'm not. Thanks.

Comment: maybe if you were more specific as to what you want the text to be under what condition, it would be easier to give you a solution

Comment: @BradBall Well, the initial state of the buttons should have the text "Intrigued." When the user clicks on a button, it sends a post request (changes ```this.state.eventifySent``` from false to true), and the button at that index should change to 'Eventify sent.' If I wasn't clear, simply asking is enough, no need to be rude about it.

Answer (score 0):

When you set eventifySent to true this expression always evaluates to false:

```
!this.state.eventifySent && this.state.disabledButton !== i
```

Therefore you'll always get 'intrigued'.

If you turn it around a little, it should work:

```
this.state.eventifySent && this.state.disabledButton === i ? 'Eventify Sent' : 'Intrigued'
```